# Python's equivalent of R's seq_len, slice, and where?

Tags: python, numpy

Transitioning from R to Python, and I am having a difficult time replicating the following code:

```
df = df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(seq_len(min(which(F < 1 & d == 8), n()))
```

Sample Data:

```
ID     Price        F         D
 1      10.1       1          NAN
 1      10.4       1          NAN 
 1      10.6      .8           8
 1      8.1       .8          NAN
 1      8.5       .8          NAN 
 2      22.4       2          NAN
 2      22.1       2          NAN
 2      21.1      .9           8
 2      20.1      .9          NAN
 2      20.1      .9           6
```

with the desired output:

```
ID     Price       F           D
 1      10.1       1          NAN
 1      10.4       1          NAN 
 2      22.4       2          NAN
 2      22.1       2          NAN
```

I believe the code in python would include some sort of:
np.where, cumcount(), and slice.

However, I have no idea how I would go about doing this. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: To anyone in the future who comes to my question in hopes to finding a solution - yatu's solution worked fine - but I have worked my way into another solution which i found to be a bit more easier to read:

```
df['temp'] = np.where((df['F'] < 1) & (df['D'] == 8), 1, 0)
mask = df.groupby(ID)['temp'].cumsum().eq(0)
df[mask]
```

I've read up on masking a bit and it really does help simplify the complexities of python quite a bit!

Comment: Could you give some details on the logic behind this?

Comment: Do you want to do this with plain `list`/`dict`, `numpy`, `pandas`, ...?

Comment: I have some data and as soon as the factor becomes < 1 and distro == 8, the data becomes too volatile afterwards, therefore I want to delete everything after this criteria is met @yatu

Comment: numpy or pandas would be preferred @MisterMiyagi

Comment: if pandas, pretty sure you could use a `groupby`

Comment: but how would I go about doing it? something like... df.groupby('ID').np.where(Factor < 1 and Distro == 8, slice(...), )) ? im not sure how to go about it @SuperStew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could index the dataframe using the conditions bellow:

```
c1 = ~df.Distro.eq(8).groupby(df.ID).cumsum()
c2 = df.Factor.lt(1).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().eq(0)
df[c1 & c2]

   ID  Price  Factor  Distro
0   1   10.1     1.0    NAN
1   1   10.4     1.0    NAN
5   2   22.4     2.0    NAN
6   2   22.1     2.0    NAN
```

Note that by taking the `.cumsum` of a boolean series you are essentially propagating the `True` values, so as soon as a `True` appears the remaining values will be `True`. This result, having been negated can be used to remove rows from the dataframe as soon as a value appears.

---

**Details**

The following dataframe shows the original dataframe along with the conditions used to index it. In this case given that the specified criteria takes place in the same rows, both conditions show the same behaviour:

```
df.assign(c1=c1, c2=c2)

   ID  Price  Factor Distro     c1     c2
0   1   10.1     1.0    NAN   True   True
1   1   10.4     1.0    NAN   True   True
2   1   10.6     0.8      8  False  False
3   1    8.1     0.8    NAN  False  False
4   1    8.5     0.8    NAN  False  False
5   2   22.4     2.0    NAN   True   True
6   2   22.1     2.0    NAN   True   True
7   2   21.1     0.9      8  False  False
8   2   20.1     0.9    NAN  False  False
9   2   20.1     0.9      6  False  False
```

Comment: hey @yatu, for d2 - i am getting the following error: TypeError: Could not operate 1 with block values Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int' ... any idea how to go about resolving this. Thank you so much for your time btw, I will make this up

Comment: Hmm looks like one of your columns in os type `timestamp`? Make sure they are `ints`